# Apache NiFi - login issue when entering username and password

Tags: apache-nifi

I installed Apache NiFi locally. (`https://localhost:8443/nifi`).
I set up the config:

```
<provider>
        <identifier>single-user-provider</identifier>
        <class>org.apache.nifi.authentication.single.user.SingleUserLoginIdentityProvider</class>
        <property name="Username">test@gmail.com</property>
        <property name="Password">123456789011</property>
</provider>
```

But when I try to log in (UI), I have an issue: `The supplied username and password are not valid.`

I use `./nifi.sh set-single-user-credentials` command to set up the username and password.

What should I do to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

1. first you need to stop the nifi in case it's running,check status by command
   --> **./nifi.sh status**
   (make sure you are in bin folder of nifi installation directory)
   the output you will get
   Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
   NiFi home: /home/user/nifi-1.21.0-bin/nifi-1.21.0

Bootstrap Config File: /home/user/nifi-1.21.0-bin/nifi-1.21.0/conf/bootstrap.conf

2023-04-11 17:01:17,418 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command Apache NiFi is not running
2) in case its running stop it by
---> **./nifi.sh stop**
then,

3)give login info by command
--> **./nifi.sh set-single-user-credentials**  
(password atleast having 12 character, and remove <>)
4)then start nifi
--> **./nifi.sh start**
5) then open your nifi ui on web as per host and port info available in nifi-app.log file and enter your username and password as per step 2,
and here you go .

Answer (score 0):

In windows OS, after restart, it worked charming!